# postgresql-setup --initdb with custom data directory

Tags: postgresql, centos

I am trying to setup Postgres 12 on Centos 8.
Postgres shall be installed in the default directory i.e. `/var/lib/pgsql`, however I want the data directory to be in `/data/pgsql`

I want to use postgresql-setup as root, as I believe it will create systemd service files along with it, rather than using pg_ctl or running initdb as postgres user.

However, if I try

```
$ postgresql-setup --initdb --pgdata=/data/pgsql/
```

I will receive the following error.

```
postgresql-setup: unrecognized option '--pgdata=/data/pgsql'
FATAL: can't parse arguments
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

If you wish to place your data in a custom directory `/pgdata/14/data`, create the directory with the correct `permissions`:

```bash
mkdir -p /pgdata/14/data
sudo chown postgres:postgres /pgdata/14/data
```

Then get `systemctl` to create a `service` file:

```bash
sudo systemctl edit postgresql-14.service
```

As mentioned above, just add the `PGDATA` location:

```bash
[Service]
Environment=PGDATA=/pgdata/14/data
```

This will create a `/etc/systemd/system/postgresql-14.service.d/override.conf` file. This will be merged with the original service file.

To check its content:

```bash
# cat /etc/systemd/system/postgresql-14.service.d/override.conf
[Service]
Environment=PGDATA=/pgdata/14/data
```

Reload systemd:

```bash
# systemctl daemon-reload
```

Initialize the PostgreSQL data directory:

```bash
sudo /usr/pgsql-14/bin/postgresql-14-setup initdb
```

Start and enable the service:

```bash
sudo systemctl enable postgresql-14
sudo systemctl start postgresql-14
```

Comment: I assume that this does not work for the first installation of PostgreSQL? Since there is no `postgres` user before the `initdb` after installation. Is this true? If so, how can one specify cluster location right after the first installation of PostgreSQL?

Comment: It does work, at least for postgresql14 on RH7 - the user `postgres` is present before running `initdb`

Answer (score 1):

I've found the easiest way to move the database to its own drive is to move the postgres home folder prior to creating the db.

```
mv /var/lib/pgsql /home/postgres
usermod -d /home/postgres postgres
sed -i 's|/var/lib/pgsql|/home/postgres|g' /usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service
sed -i 's|/var/lib/pgsql|/home/postgres|g' /usr/bin/postgresql-setup
systemctl daemon-reload
/usr/bin/postgresql-setup --initdb
```

While most of the commands are relatively self-explanatory, the `sed -i 's|x|y|g' file` is a simple one-line *find x*/*replace with y* using `sed` command.

What's sad is that even though the `/usr/bin/postgresql-setup` script has `POSTGRES_HOMEDIR=/var/lib/pgsql` variable to define the home, it still has `/var/lib/pgsql` hard-coded in other places. Even sadder that the script does not just read the configured home from `/etc/passwd` file.

Answer (score 0):

> /usr/pgsql-12/bin/initdb --pgdata=/data/pgsql

Answer (score 0):

postgresql-setup doesn't create systemd service file.

You must create it from scratch /lib/systemd/system/postgresql-14.service or create config file for default systemd service file.

For example /lib/systemd/system/db-test.service, which contain path to desired db

```
# Location of database directory
Environment=PGDATA=/data/pgsql/db_test
```

then run

```
# systemctl daemon-reload
# systemctl db-test.service
# /usr/bin/postgresql-14-setup initdb db-test
Initializing database ... OK
```

and voilà

```
# ls -l /data/pgsql/db_test/pg_hba.conf 
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres 4577 Feb 25 15:19 /data/pgsql/db_test/pg_hba.conf
```

If you want use default service then create config /lib/systemd/system/postgresql-14.service.d/postgresql-14.conf for service /lib/systemd/system/postgresql-14.service

For example

```
# cat /lib/systemd/system/postgresql-14.service.d/postgresql-14.conf
[Service]
Environment=PGDATA=/data/pgsql/postgresql-14
```